# Why do methods on pointers work when the pointer is a variable, but not otherwise?

Tags: pointers, go

When running the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Bar struct {
    name string
}

func (foo Bar) testFunc() {
    fmt.Println(foo.name)
}

func doTest(pointer *Bar) {
    pointer.testFunc() // run `testFunc` on the pointer (even though it expects a value of type `Bar`, not `*Bar`)
}

func main() {
    var baz Bar = Bar{
        name: "Johnny Appleseed",
    }

    doTest(&baz) // send a pointer of `baz` to `doTest()`
}
```

The output reads: `Johnny Appleseed`. I would have thought I would have encountered an error for calling `testFunc()` on a pointer.

After that, I tried switching out `doTest(&baz)` for `&baz.testFunc()`. Then I received the error:

```
tmp/sandbox667065035/main.go:24: baz.testFunc() used as value
```

Why do I only get the error when calling `baz.testFunc()` directly instead of through another function? Wouldn't calling `doTest(&baz)` and `&baz.testFunc()` do the exact same thing, as `doTest(pointer *Bar)` simply calls `pointer.testFunc()`?

*[Playground 1 (`doTest(&baz)`)](https://play.golang.org/p/xotjr1iKOt)*

*[Playground 2 (`&baz.testFunc()`)](https://play.golang.org/p/Tqg7LSl8LA)*

Comment: Go has automatic pointer dereferencing with (dot) calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of automatic derefencing of [method values](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values)

> As with selectors, a reference to a non-interface method with a value receiver using a pointer will automatically dereference that pointer: pt.Mv is equivalent to (*pt).Mv.

For the second line, you have this error because you take the address of the **result** of testFunc which doesn't return any value.
What you tried to do is the following:

```
(&baz).testFunc()
```

which works as expected